# gitlab-ci with web pack: what image do I need?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gitlab-ci

Our applications uses webpack. I need all my tests to run and artifacts to be created by web pack;

In my package.json, "build" script is defined:

```
..
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js -p"
..
```

and this is my gitlab-ci.yml for now:

image: iteamdev/node-webpack:latest

```
variables:
  NODE_ENV: "development" # required, because we need to install devDependencies

stages:
  - build

compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm -v
    - npm install -qs # install all dependencies (and devDependencies)
    - npm run build # run webpack, set NODE_ENV=production
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - dist/
```

What options do I have for the "image"? Is the one i'm using good for my needs? Should I work with a specific version?

Comment: `node:?`, or node-based image is the only correct answer. Everything else can be installed via `npm install` or globally

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably recommend using `image: node:4.2.2` for your image.

Comment: Any particular reason to use this over the newer node version? It looks like the question is specifically about webpack, which is not included in this image.

Comment: @JoshNoe we used node 4.2.2 at the time for GitLab CE, I don't think there's any reason to use that version specifically versus newer versions.